# How to post data back on webpage in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, postback

Just started working with Node.js and now i successfuly configured Postgres database. I can fetched the records from db and I can also see records cound in console.log.
But now i am little bit stuck how to post data back on same page.

I have page called index with two text fields and one submit button. When i submit my data with username and id, i receive this request in request.post method.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var userid = req.body.userid;

    // method which take parameters and return records from db
    getRecords(userid, username, function (result, found) {
        if (found) {
            console.log(result.rows.length);
        }
    });
});
```

After successful transcation from db, I can see the record count in console. But now how can i post this data into the same page (index.ejs) from where i received this request.

I tried to do

```
res.send('/', { title: result.rows.length });
```

and in ejs file

```
<p>Count is <%= title %></p>
```

but i received error that "title" is not defined.
So how can i display count and how can i display the list of records which i fetched from database.

Answer (score 0):

Just write red.send(result) or if you want to send multiple responses you can red.write(result) and remember to caught the result sent from nodejs in your webpage

Comment: can you expalin bit more... how to do that and what to write in ejs file. I wrote <p>count is  <%= result.rows.length %></p> in ejs file.. but same error, result is not defined

Comment: If you are using ajax call from page to server for dB query and fetching result than you need to write the code in on success block of ajax call from client. I dont know about how to do in ejs, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `res.render()` if you want to render a template with some variables. For example:

```
// or res.render('index', ...)
res.render('index.ejs', { title: result.rows.length });
```

This assumes you have your app's views settings set up properly.